# Баллы для получения меток

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, знаки

Как зарабатывать баллы для знаков по меткам. Например, по питону так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того, как мой ответ по питону приняли, ничего не изменилось. За что присуждаются баллы рейттинга?

Comment: Принятые ответы не влияют на эти баллы, только голоса "за" и "против".

Comment: Поэтому, кстати, я никогда особо не топлю за то, чтобы мои ответы принимали.

Comment: @insolor ? (5 симв)

Comment: Просто повышение репутации - это уже не интересно, интересны значки. Принятие ответа дает только репутацию, но никак не влияет на процесс получения значков, поэтому я не вижу смысла, например, под каждым вопросом, где я ответил, напоминать автору вопроса, что ответы нужно принимать.

Comment: А почему вы на SO отвечаете на вопросы?

Comment: Потому что я люблю отвечать на интересные мне вопросы. Можно сказать, что я в какой-то степени люблю учить других и учиться самому в процессе.

Comment: @insolor, на некоторые влияет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, на знаки за метки - нет.

Comment: @insolor, не все знаки за метки ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy но за [python] знак за метку ;)